# Enable php for apache(Oracle http server)

Tags: php, apache

I want to enable php for apache (Oracle http server). I just want to see static php pages. No database connection, no mysql.
Currently we have apache and some websites on it in html. A developer wants to write php static pages. Currenlty they are shown as text by the browser so I guess we need to make apache show php.
Developer wants to write php pages to centralise the code. Currently when changes are needed on the page they have to change 300 pages. With php they can avoid this by making a static header.php and footer.php.
So I currently have an apache without php support. What are the steps I need to follow to show the below page?
`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
Download and install latest php from where?
What changes are needed in http.conf?
Thanks

Comment: What OS is your server running? How have you installed Apache2? Do you have PHP installed?

Comment: O/S is RHEL 7.Apache2 yes. No php installed on the O/S. How do I install it